# The closed distance point for linear subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be real Banach space with closed linear subspaces $Y$ and $Z$ such that $Y \cap Z = \{ 0\}$, $X = Y \bigoplus Z$:
> $$
> \lambda = \inf \{ \|y - z\| : \|y\| = \|z\| = 1\} \geq 0 
> $$
> where $y \in Y, z \in Z$

I am trying to show that $\lambda$ is strictly positive i.e $\lambda > 0$. My attempt is I am using the parallelogram identity:

$$
\| y - z\|^2 = 2(\|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2) - \|y+z\|^2 \geq 2(2) - \lambda^{2} = 4 - \lambda^2
$$

Since $\lambda \geq 0$, I have that: $4- \lambda^2 \leq 4$.

Taking the infimum for both sides I deduce that:

$$
\inf \| y - z\|  = 2  
$$

Is there some part in my proof that is not right? I think that $\lambda$ can be strictly positive trivially if $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$ but here there is an assumption for that.

Comment: You are assuming the parallelogram law, which does not hold in any Banach space.  Have you already learned the closed graph Theorem?  You can't get away without it!

Comment: I see. I think I partially understand what you mean. Is it to show $Y \bigoplus Z$ is closed in $X$?

Comment: Well, $Y\oplus Z$ is equal to $X$, hence closed, right? I suggest you try proving that the projection from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous using the closed graph Theorem.

Comment: Ruy is correct that you went astray right at the start, but there is another problem. You have shown an expression of the form $$x \ge B \le C$$ (note the directions on those inequalities), then claimed that this shows $\inf x = C$. That doesn't follow at all. In fact, you haven't shown any relationship between $\|y-z\|^2$ and $4$.